# C# - Xamarin.Forms - Can not access a closed Stream

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, itext, itext7

I am using itext7 in Xamarin.Forms application. I am trying to take a PDF file from a Stream, use PdfAcroForm in itext7 to write to it, but when I do I get this error: Can not access a closed Stream. I feel I have tried everything, here is my original code:

```
MemoryStream outFile = new MemoryStream();

var streamFile = await App.GraphClient.Me.Drive.Items[item.Id].Content.Request().GetAsync();

PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(streamFile), new PdfWriter(outFile));

PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdf, true);

IDictionary<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.GetFormFields();

PdfFormField toSet;
fields.TryGetValue("Full_Names", out toSet);
toSet.SetValue("aaa");

form.FlattenFields();
pdf.Close();

await App.GraphClient.Me.Drive.Items[newFolder.Id].ItemWithPath(item.Name).Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(outFile);
```

Then I tried with using and set the position of the stream to 0 and flush my stream and that still did not work.

```
using (MemoryStream outFile = new MemoryStream())
{
    var streamFile = await App.GraphClient.Me.Drive.Items[item.Id].Content.Request().GetAsync();

    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(streamFile), new PdfWriter(outFile));

    PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdf, true);

    IDictionary<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.GetFormFields();

    PdfFormField toSet;
    fields.TryGetValue("Full_Names", out toSet);
    toSet.SetValue("aaa");

    form.FlattenFields();
    pdf.Close();

    outFile.Flush();
    outFile.Position = 0;

    await App.GraphClient.Me.Drive.Items[newFolder.Id].ItemWithPath(item.Name).Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(outFile);
}
```

When I remove this line...pdf.Close(); the pdf get written, but when I open it in OneDrive its corrupted...What am I doing wrong?

Comment: which specific line causes the exception?

Comment: Right Here: outFile.Position = 0;

Comment: And when I remove that line its at the end of the using statement.

Comment: first, MemoryStream Close() doesn't do anything so that's not required.  Second, my wild guess would be that pdf.Close() also closes the related stream.  3rd, I'd try writing the final PDF to a file first, then opening it again in order to upload it

Comment: Yea, when I don't close the PdfDocument, I don't get the error anymore and the new file is created, but I can't open it and the file size is 0

Comment: @Jason can I see an example of what you would do?

Comment: Nevermind, figured out...posting code now.

Answer (score 2):

This worked:

```
using (MemoryStream outFile = new MemoryStream())
{
    var streamFile = await App.GraphClient.Me.Drive.Items[item.Id].Content.Request().GetAsync();

    using(PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(streamFile), new PdfWriter(outFile)))
    {

        pdf.SetCloseWriter(false);

        PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdf, true);

        IDictionary<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.GetFormFields();

        PdfFormField toSet;
        fields.TryGetValue("Full_Names", out toSet);
        toSet.SetValue(Customer_Name.Text + " " + Customer_LName.Text);

        fields.TryGetValue("Full_Names0", out toSet);
        toSet.SetValue(Customer_Name.Text + " " + Customer_LName.Text);

        fields.TryGetValue("Full_Names1", out toSet);
        toSet.SetValue(Customer_Name.Text + " " + Customer_LName.Text);

        fields.TryGetValue("Address0", out toSet);
        toSet.SetValue(Address1.Text);

        fields.TryGetValue("City0", out toSet);
        toSet.SetValue(City.Text);

        fields.TryGetValue("Province0", out toSet);
        toSet.SetValue(Province.Text);

        fields.TryGetValue("Phone0", out toSet);
        toSet.SetValue(Phone2Main.Text);

        fields.TryGetValue("Email0", out toSet);
        toSet.SetValue(Email.Text);

        form.FlattenFields();
    }

    outFile.Flush();
    outFile.Position = 0;

    await App.GraphClient.Me.Drive.Items[newFolder.Id].ItemWithPath(item.Name).Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(outFile);
}
```